# React Native Issue:

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

Can anyone please help me to resolve the issue?

I am running the app and i got this error in node js

[Image show the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1aKO.png)

Comment: can you please post your json and some snippet of code ... you json format having issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to:

```
killall node
rm -rf node_modules/
```

Then uninstall the application if the application has been installed, and make sure all port nodes have stopped.